# Rails 6 Search Form with Wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
scope :formula_like, ->(formula) { where(‘formula ILIKE ?‘, formula.gsub(‘*’, ‘%’)) }
```

I also tried

```
scope :formula_like, ->(formula) { where(‘formula LIKE ?‘, formula.gsub(‘*’, ‘%’)) }
```

no filtering happened, on either.
What am I doing wrong?

Search > N* -> return > NE, NB, NI, NG

Search > *E -> return > NE, CE, ME

Worked fine on Rails 5

now not on Rails 6.0.4.1 and Ruby 2.6.8p205

_search_form.html.erb

```
<%= render layout: 'shared/collapse_search_form', locals: { tab_param: :phase, text_field: :text_search, show: any_searches? } do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :formula_like, "Formula", class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= text_field_tag :formula_like, params[:formula_like], class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "Dimensions", nil, class: "control-label" %><br/>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= number_field_tag :width_greater_than, params[:width_greater_than], placeholder: "Width", step: "any", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= number_field_tag :length_greater_than, params[:length_greater_than], placeholder: "Length", step: "any", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "Date range", nil, class: "control-label" %><br/>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= text_field_tag :serial_date_after, params[:serial_date_after], placeholder: "Start", class: "form-control bootstrap-datepicker" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= text_field_tag :serial_date_before, params[:serial_date_before], placeholder: "End", class: "form-control bootstrap-datepicker" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

No Error. Nothing happens.
[image: this is what i'm getting after entering wildcard in form.]

Comment: Are those the "quotes" you are using? Additionally what do you mean no filtering, you have not shown where or how you are calling this scope. Are you receiving any errors or do you have error handling that might be disguising the issue?

Comment: what about the 'quotes'? yes quotes in the code. should the wild card in the form be used with quotes? instead of N* it should be N'*'?

Comment: The code here has `‘formula LIKE ?‘` with typographic quotes - such as you would commonly see in code that has been pasted from MS Word and is not syntactically correct ruby. `‘` is treated as an identifier and not a quote - `‘ = 'hello world'; puts ‘`.

Comment: The quotes you posted are not apostrophes. They are right/left single quotes, which would raise a `NameError` most likely. Additionally while you have updated the post you still have not shown where or how you call this scope in the code. So we have no idea why you think it should filter or why it does not filter.

Comment: No NameError. Does the scope not get called in the _search_form_html.erb on line 5, or i'm not reading this correctly.

Comment: @Stephanie that is just a form, somewhere somehow the information submitted by this form needs to be processed through the backend. Are you using some kind of framework or library (like `ActiveAdmin`) that you believe should be handling this for you?

Comment: When you submit the form, do you see the value of the formula field in the submitted html GET command? (look at the server log). Do you see a query being executed, what does the sql query look like?